# $env:USERNAME not defined when filtering on Get-ADuser?

Tags: powershell

Can anyone explain why this fails:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $env:USERNAME}
Get-ADUser : Variable: 'env' found in expression: $env is not defined.
```

But this succeeds:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $u=$env:USERNAME

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $u}

DistinguishedName : CN<snip>
```

Is the above the most elegant workaround or am I missing something?

Comment: And what happen if you try like that : `Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "$env:USERNAME"}`

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($env:USERNAME)'"`

Comment: My second example in my answer is probably the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, this works too:

```
Get-aduser "$samaccountname"
```

or

```
Get-aduser "$env:USERNAME"
```

Don't even need to bother with "-Filter" if you are passing the samaccountname

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it so I've marked as correct (although all answers were more correct than my workaround).  Is the sam account name always guaranteed to be the same as the username?  I had wondered about using that, but wasn't sure it was a cast iron guarantee?

Comment: I have never run into an instance where the sam account name is not the username for the user.  I think it is a pretty safe assumption to make.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$username = $env:USERNAME
Get-ADUser -Filter 'SamAccountName -eq $username'
```

And this works too:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($env:USERNAME)'"
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not write the Filter as scriptblock. It should be a **string**

Comment: I didnt test it before, just made an assumption. Now i tested and corrected it to two working examples.

Comment: The first one shouldn't work because of the single quotes. That way, variable `$username` will not be expanded.

Comment: @Theo Both are tested and works. Updated with Printscreen.

Comment: Thanks - the second example in particular allows me to the see the mechanics of where I went wrong.